# How to use a parabola formula in AS3 for firing an arrow that will always intercept a given point

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, math, physics

First note: mathematically, I'm not that skilled at all.

I played a game on iPhone a while back where you press a point, and an arrow fires from your castle which will always intersect the point you pressed. I wanted to make a similar game, thinking it would be an easy quick make; then I ran into the realization that the mathematics for this is actually beyond my skill level.

I'm assuming they're using a parabola formula or something which would determine the velocity and angle needed when the arrow is launched for the arrow to always intersect the clicked point.

I only vaguely remember how parabolas work from school and have no chance of working out any formulas.

Any mathematical help or ideas that might be easier to implement would be great.

I want to end up with a function in my castle like so:

```
package
{
    import avian.framework.objects.AvElement;

    public class Castle extends AvElement
    {
        /**
         * Fires an arrow from this
         * @param ix The x intersection point
         * @param iy The y intersection point
         */
        public function fire(ix:Number, iy:Number):void
        {
            var ar:Arrow = new Arrow();

            ar.x = x;
            ar.y = y;

            // define angle and velocity based on ix, iy
            // ar.fireAngle = ??
            // ar.fireVelocity = ??

            parent.addChild(ar);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update** as per questions in comments:

There will be no forces applied to the arrow such as wind, friction, etc. Also, the starting point of the arrow is fixed throughout the game (at the castle).

Here is an example image for slightly more clarity:
[image: Arrow path]

To be as clear as possible:

1. Arrow always begins its journey from a fixed point (say: 40, 120).
2. The arrow must always intercept a given coordinate.
3. A realistic as possible path is something I'd like to achieve (obviously I can just fire an arrow straight to intercept any point, but the **goal** is to have the arrow first rise, then descend; passing through the desired coordinate at the most realistic point in its journey).

**Note:** To avoid the issue of there being infinite possible parabolas - the velocity of the arrow can be fixed - just look at defining the angle the arrow can leave at.

Comment: Just a quick note: you'll also need a starting point (as well as the destination)

Comment: So you click where you want the arrow to end up?  You'll need origin coordinates too.  The angle and velocity will be a paired range of values, unless one is fixed.  Obviously the velocity has to be at least the minimum to achieve the distance at the optimal angle.  But if the angle is to very, then the velocity can too.  No air resistance, wind, at all?  Earth standard gravity?

Comment: This [graph and the equations under it](http://www.physics.brocku.ca/~aknigavk/1P21/Kinematics/projectile-motion-1.jpg) are useful.

Comment: The origin will be fixed and there will be no other forces applied to the arrow - see update to question. :)

Comment: Unfortunately you will probably need some linear algebra for this which is nontrivial.  You need to plug in the target's coordinates for x and y in the two equations to the left and solve for v_0 and t.  There are an infinite number of solutions to that system.  You should look into methods of solving systems of equations next.

Comment: Yes it's under-constrained. What this means in the real world: Imagine you have a target at the other end of a field. To hit it, I could shoot an arrow hard and at a flat angle, or I could raise my bow and shoot more softly, or anything in between.

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean. Does it help if I could specify a parameter which defines how "curved" the parabola along which the arrow will follow is?

Comment: You'd probably want to set the problem up so that the arrow has minimal kinetic energy at the start. I think this will give you the most "natural" result. I can write out the maths tomorrow if nobody else offers a solution, but right this second I don't have time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The flight path of a projectile through a gravitational field can be described
by applying the [equations of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion)

The equations I will use are

```
1. v = u + at
2. s = ut + (at^2)/2
```

where

s = the distance between initial and final positions
u = the initial velocity
v = the final velocity
a = the constant acceleration
t = the time taken to move from the initial state to the final state

Ok. To animate this arrow we will calculate its new velocity and position at
regular intervals (every frame) based on its previous velocity, position and
acceleration. Acceleration in this case is entirely due to gravity.

Lets simplify and measure the time intervals in frames rather than seconds.
This gives us t = 1 for the above equations allowing us to rewrite them as

```
1. v = u + a*1           => v = u + a
2. s = u*1 + (a*1^2)/2   => s = u + a/2
```

Now in the x direction the acceleration, a = 0 (we're not taking drag into
account). In the y direction a = g, acceleration due to gravity. If we rewite
these equations for resolved for each axis we get

for x:

```
1. vx = ux + 0        => vx = ux (no change so we'll ignore this)
2. sx = ux + 0/2      => sx = ux (convenient eh?)
```

for y:

```
1. vy = uy + g
2. sy = uy + g/2
```

So lets plug them into a sample script

```
public class Arrow extends Sprite
{
    //g is constant
    //it's actually closer to 10 but this is our world
    public static const g:Number = 2;

    //our arrow
    private var arrow:Shape;

    //start velocities
    private var ux:Number;
    private var uy:Number;

    public function Arrow()
    {
        arrow = new Shape();
        arrow.graphics.lineStyle( 1, 0 );
        arrow.graphics.lineTo( 30, 0 );
    }

    public function fire( vx:Number, vy:Number ):void
    {
        ux = vx;
        uy = vy;
        addChild( arrow );
        addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, fly );
    }

    private function fly( e:Event ):void
    {
        //lets use our equations
        var sx:Number = ux;       //distance moved in x dir

        var vy:Number = uy + g    //new velocity in y dir
        var sy:Number = uy + g/2  //distance moved in y dir

        //apply to arrow
        arrow.x += sx;
        arrow.y += sy;

        //save new y velocity
        uy = vy;

        //extra bonus rotation of arrow to point in the right direction
        arrow.rotation = Math.atan2( uy, ux ) * 180 / Math.PI;

    }

}
```

Comment: Looks really convincing mate, I'll have to try it out when I get a moment. +1 for the effort either way :)

Comment: @Marty Wallace No problem, I enjoyed writing it, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with basically no math:

```
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Arrow extends Shape
{
    private var xVelocity:Number;
    private var yVelocity:Number;

    public function Arrow(fireAngle:Number, fireVelocity:Number)
    {
        xVelocity = Math.cos(fireAngle) * fireVelocity;
        yVelocity = Math.sin(fireAngle) * fireVelocity;

        graphics.beginFill(0);
        graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 5);
        graphics.endFill();

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
    }
    private function enterFrameHandler(ev:Event):void
    {
        x += xVelocity;
        y += yVelocity;
        yVelocity += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it that hard to run it and see?

Comment: Sorry, this will give the effect of what I want, but the goal is to have the arrow intersect a point. Having the arrow manoeuvre realistically is not a concern.